# Pulseaudio loopback into headphones

Tags: audio, alsa, pulse-audio, loopback

I have headphones and a mic attached to my computer. My headphones are tight and block out external noise far too well, and so I find myself shouting at the mic.

Is there any way of setting up Pulseaudio so that it "echos" the microphone input back at me? Even better, any way for it to only switch to this configuration when the headphones are switched on?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, it helps if you know what it is you want to search for.

Found the following article: https://endless.ersoft.org/pulseaudio-loopback/

Turns out the solution to my particular problem is to load a pulseaudio "loopback" module.

First, find the names of your devices:

```
pactl list | grep "Name: "
```

Select the sink (i.e. output) you want and create a virtual loopback device for it - in my case, the command is

```
pactl load-module module-loopback sink=bluez_sink.44_34_8B_E0_C6_5D.a2dp_sink
```

It will give you a number (In my case, it was 34) - hold on to that number, you may need it later.

Now that appears in the sound settings under the "Applications" tab as "Unknown", but `pavucontrol` (my favourite volume controller for many many reasons) shows it in the Playback tab as "Loopback from ..." and the name of the input device.

There is a delay of about quater of a second, which might get annoying fast - we'll have to see!

**[update]**

Unfortunately, despite the fact you gave the device a specific output device (in my case, bluetooth headphones) it still seems to fall back to the default speaker once you've disconnected the headphones. Remember I said keep hold of that number - you'll need it here:

```
pactl unload-module 34
```

As I say, I don't know how much I'm going to actually use this, as the delay is a bit distracting. Will try it a few times with and without. I'm sure there's a way to listen for system events and detect when the headphones are reconnected / disconnected. If I decide it's worth it, I'll post whatever script I come up with here.